# "the bigger RegSS, the better the estimated model performs" are we sure?

Tags: regression, anova, multiple-regression, predictive-models, modeling

Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares#Definition) says "the bigger ESS (or RegSS, SSR, etc), the better the estimated model performs".

Surely this is wrong. ESS is the sum of the squared distances between the fitted values and the sample mean. $$ESS = \sum (\hat{y}_i-\bar{y})^2$$Surely the smaller ESS is, the closer the fitted values are to the sample mean, which is a good sign!

On the other hand, if we have a large ESS, it means that the fitted values are very distant from the sample mean, which is bad.

> Is Wikipedia wrong or is there  a flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Is your objective to estimate the mean of the $y_i$ or is it to fit a linear model to the $y_i$?  You write as if it's the former, while the Wikipedia article is devoted to the latter objective.

Comment: @whuber I'm studying the topic of linear regression, so yes I'm trying to fit a linear model!

Comment: That's not what your argument suggests: you explicitly state it's a "good sign" when your linear model is essentially the same as the sample mean.  That the same as saying the linear model is no better than the sample mean--which means it's no improvement over the mean itself.

Comment: I'm fitting the linear model where $$y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$$ with $\varepsilon_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Comment: I think the difference occurs because Wikipedia is referring to prediction while the OP is asking about the fit. So Wikipedia is giving a larger value.

Comment: @whuber okay I understand what you mean. So basically if it was close to the sample mean, I could just explain the model as $y_i \sim N(\bar{y},\sigma^2)$ instead of recurring to the linear model? It does make sense. But at the same time, do you not want the model to be "close" to the data? And after all the sample means comes from averaging the data

Comment: @MichaelChernick and whuber are you saying that: if I am trying to fit a linear model, I want a big RegSS, while if I'm estimating the mean I want a small RegSS?

Comment: In my case what I am saying is that fitting the model is more accurate than predicting a new value using the fitted model.

Comment: Also because if we know that $RegSS = SS-RSS$ and we know that $SS = $ variation of the data from the sample mean, $RSS = $ variation of the model from the data (or vice versa), then we have $$RegSS = \text{var data from mean}-\text{var data from model}$$.

Comment: @MichaelChernick okay we know that. But how does that relate to this? If I'm fitting a linear model on some data and I calculate RegSS, what do I want to see? Small RegSS or large RegSS?

Comment: It has to do with what the Wikipedia link is discussing.

Comment: @MichaelChernick at the beginning it says "The ESS.." ".. is a quantity used in describing how well a model represents the data being modelled". So Wikipedia is discussing the same problem. I have some data and I am trying to model them using a regression model (in my case linear)